# Skipping Sunday Occurrences in ORACLE Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(CURRENT_SURFACE) AS TOTALYESTERDAYPAINTING 
FROM PAINTING_HIST 
WHERE TO_CHAR (PAINT_ENTRY_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1, 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
AND PROJECT_NAME = :projName
```

But the problem is this includes sunday as well, if yesterday is sunday.
How do I skip sunday and if today's monday then yesterday's saturday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing dates as strings isn't generally a good idea; it prevents indexes being used, for a start. Using `trunc(sysdate)` gives you midnight today, so if your `paint_entry_date` is always set to midnight then you can do:

```
SELECT SUM(CURRENT_SURFACE) AS TOTALYESTERDAYPAINTING 
FROM PAINTING_HIST 
WHERE PAINT_ENTRY_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE) -
  CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'SUN'
    THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
AND PROJECT_NAME = :projName
```

The `case` statement is looking at today's day name (forcing it to English in case the session running this is in another language), and deciding whether to subtract one or two days from it.

If your column has various times of day in it then you need to do it as a range:

```
SELECT SUM(CURRENT_SURFACE) AS TOTALYESTERDAYPAINTING 
FROM PAINTING_HIST 
WHERE PAINT_ENTRY_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) -
  CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'SUN'
    THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
AND PAINT_ENTRY_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) -
  CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'SUN'
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
AND PROJECT_NAME = :projName
```

More generically, where the bind variable `days` is the number of days you want to look back:

```
SELECT SUM(CURRENT_SURFACE) AS TOTALYESTERDAYPAINTING 
FROM PAINTING_HIST 
WHERE PAINT_ENTRY_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) -
  CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - :days, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'SUN'
    THEN :days + 1 ELSE :days END
AND PAINT_ENTRY_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) -
  CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - :days, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'SUN'
    THEN :days ELSE :days - 1 END
AND PROJECT_NAME = :projName;
```

Now if `sysdate - :days` is a Sunday, it looks back an extra day.

If you want to get the data for the last seven days but skip whichever date is the Sunday you can use:

```
SELECT TRUNC(PAINT_ENTRY_DATE),
  SUM(CURRENT_SURFACE) AS TOTALYESTERDAYPAINTING 
FROM PAINTING_HIST 
WHERE PAINT_ENTRY_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7
AND PAINT_ENTRY_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND TO_CHAR(PAINT_ENTRY_DATE, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') != 'SUN'
AND PROJECT_NAME = :projName
GROUP BY TRUNC(PAINT_ENTRY_DATE)
ORDER BY TRUNC(PAINT_ENTRY_DATE);
```

That will find all records for the seven days up to yesterday; so if run today it would get 2014-09-06 to 2014-09-14, but would then exclude the 14th because that was Sunday. If you run it tomorrow it would get 2014-09-07 to 2014-09-15 and still exclude the 14th.

Comment: Awesome, so if i wanna check SUM(CURRENT_SURFACE) two days ago and skipping sunday. Do i have to change `WHERE PAINT_ENTRY_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 2, 'MM/DD/YYYY') -
  CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'MON'
    THEN 2 ELSE 1 END` ????

Comment: @marmar - so you need the number of days you look back to be flexible, but always want to skip Sunday if that's the day you land on? Specifically for two days you'd need to change both the `then`/`else` sections but also change the `MON` to `TUE`; which can be generalised more simply.

Comment: yes thats true. my intention is to get a weekly chart that shows the data progress. but i dont want the sunday occurences to disrupt the data flows.

Comment: @marmar - ok, but if you're always looking at a week's worth of data, you'd be better of doing a single query that excludes Sunday, and grouping by the `paint_entry_date`? It sounds like you're planning to run 7 individual queries which would be a bit odd.

Comment: Thats my idea at first but i realized thats not efficient at all. any suggestion or tutorial on how to implement 6 days worth of data with single query ?

Comment: @marmar - that's really a different question, and closer to zaratrustra's original interpretation; but it's even simpler so I've added it anyway...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude sunday try this:

```
SELECT SUM(CURRENT_SURFACE) AS TOTALYESTERDAYPAINTING 
  FROM PAINTING_HIST 
 WHERE PAINT_ENTRY_DATE = SYSDATE - 1
   AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1, 'DAY') != 'SUNDAY'
   AND PROJECT_NAME = :projName
```

Comment: That doesn't skip back to Saturday though. (And worth mentioning that the day names are NLS-sensitive?)

Comment: @marmar provide us an input and the expected output, please. It's hard to understand what you really expect.